# Learn DirectX or Game engine?

Tags: directx, game-engine

I started learning DirectX 11 with C++. It's hard, but I think I'm doing good. 
I discovered UDK (Unreal game engine), and read that many good games like Mass Effect 1-3 was made in that engine. I consider why I should learn DirectX, when many games are already made in game engines, and it's a lot easier.
What are the pros and cons by learning DirectX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DirectX gives the capability to push pixels on screen.  Anything beyond that - physics, map models, dev tools, file formats, music, AI, networking code - is still your problem.  On the other hand, a game engine provides a comprehensive solution for most of the things you will need, but at a cost (technical constraints, learning curve, and often non-trivial amounts of $$).

It really depends on your goals and needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is to learn Graphics programming then you should choose DirectX 11 because it gives you access to low level graphics programming.
On the other hand if you want to jump right to gameplay programming UDK will allow you to step over low level graphics programming and get your hands on gameplay.

If you want to learn physics, audio, networking programming, you should take a look at Ogre3D (it's a graphics engine that as the name suggests handles the graphics, all you have to do is programming physics, gameplay).